# Metal MTLGetWarningMode + 218 SIGABRT ABORT

Tags: ios, flutter, background, location, updates

I have this error, catched by Crashlytics, Flutter, iOS:
Crashed: io.flutter.1.io
SIGABRT ABORT 0x00000001b624d414

the full error text is:

```
Crashed: io.flutter.1.io
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b624d414 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d3da8b50 pthread_kill + 272
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x19172bb74 abort + 104
3  Metal                          0x19eb219d4 MTLGetWarningMode + 218
4  IOGPU                          0x1c5828490 -[IOGPUMetalCommandBuffer pushDebugGroup:] + 242
5  Metal                          0x19eb11990 -[_MTLCommandEncoder initWithCommandBuffer:] + 884
6  IOGPU                          0x1c582a140 -[IOGPUMetalCommandEncoder initWithCommandBuffer:] + 56
7  AGXMetalA13                    0x1d54462b4 (Missing)
8  AGXMetalA13                    0x1d5189770 (Missing)
9  Flutter                        0x101c39b00 (Missing)
10 Flutter                        0x101c3c9bc (Missing)
11 Flutter                        0x101b42d84 (Missing)
12 Flutter                        0x101b5596c (Missing)
13 Flutter                        0x101b4ec70 (Missing)
14 Flutter                        0x101b6c7b8 (Missing)
15 Flutter                        0x101b4e830 (Missing)
16 Flutter                        0x101b27458 (Missing)
17 Flutter                        0x101becedc (Missing)
18 Flutter                        0x101dbfc10 (Missing)
19 Flutter                        0x101c9dfc4 (Missing)
20 Flutter                        0x101c9fe24 (Missing)
21 CoreFoundation                 0x188279fa0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
22 CoreFoundation                 0x188279ba0 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1064
23 CoreFoundation                 0x188278ffc __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 328
24 CoreFoundation                 0x188272ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1936
25 CoreFoundation                 0x18827221c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
26 Flutter                        0x101c9fd00 (Missing)
27 Flutter                        0x101c9f704 (Missing)
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d3da7cb0 _pthread_start + 320
29 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d3db0778 thread_start + 8

crash_info_entry_0
abort() called
```

This error occurs, when i use background location updates (package background_location: ^0.4.3), to determine the users location and show the location on a flutter map (flutter_map: ^0.12.0).
HAve anybody an idea, what this error means, and how to resolve/avoid it? Thanks for any help!

Comment: This error happen just in production?

Comment: yes! only in production mode, on the simulator i cannot reproduce it

Comment: Flutter github have an [issue open with this error](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76772), you can subscribe it to receive updates, but in my experience we have no user reports about this bug, just crashlytics info.

Answer (score 0):

Just today I also encountered the same problem as you. At present, it seems that it is caused by the Flutter SDK. It seems that the official has not found a specific solution. You can track the problem from here.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76772

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. Very weird and cannot reproduce or investigate this.

```
Crashed: io.flutter.1.raster
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x7964 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7378 pthread_kill + 268
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1ff50 abort + 164
3  Metal                          0xbe390 MTLGetWarningMode + 218
4  IOGPU                          0x3ba8 IOGPUResourceGetClientShared + 242
5  Metal                          0x146b0 -[_MTLCommandEncoder initWithCommandBuffer:] + 884
6  IOGPU                          0x5824 -[IOGPUMetalCommandEncoder initWithCommandBuffer:] + 56
7  AGXMetalA13                    0x108604 (Missing)
8  AGXMetalA13                    0x36c6c (Missing)
9  Flutter                        0x283418 (Missing)
10 Flutter                        0x28a508 (Missing)
11 Flutter                        0x287028 (Missing)
12 Flutter                        0x21fdc8 (Missing)
13 Flutter                        0x1877ac (Missing)
14 Flutter                        0x187b98 (Missing)
15 Flutter                        0x5566c (Missing)
16 Flutter                        0x4f9264 (Missing)
17 Flutter                        0x47e548 (Missing)
18 Flutter                        0x3b46f4 (Missing)
19 Flutter                        0x3b4c10 (Missing)
20 Flutter                        0x2ec858 (Missing)
21 Flutter                        0x3b4308 (Missing)
22 Flutter                        0x3b5c40 (Missing)
23 Flutter                        0x3b4ec4 (Missing)
24 Flutter                        0x3bd304 (Missing)
25 Flutter                        0x2eb0c8 (Missing)
26 Flutter                        0x2ee694 (Missing)
27 CoreFoundation                 0xae268 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
28 CoreFoundation                 0x32c40 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1076
29 CoreFoundation                 0x2d43c __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 328
30 CoreFoundation                 0xbc58 __CFRunLoopRun + 1944
31 CoreFoundation                 0x1f3b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
32 Flutter                        0x2ee560 (Missing)
33 Flutter                        0x2edd20 (Missing)
34 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19a4 _pthread_start + 148
35 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xea0 thread_start + 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the same is happening to me, IDK exactly what happended. It just crash one time on an iPhone XR

```
Crashed: io.flutter.1.raster
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x7964 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7378 pthread_kill + 268
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1ff50 abort + 164
3  Metal                          0xbe390 MTLGetWarningMode + 218
4  IOGPU                          0x3ba8 IOGPUResourceGetClientShared + 242
5  Metal                          0x146b0 -[_MTLCommandEncoder initWithCommandBuffer:] + 884
6  IOGPU                          0x5824 -[IOGPUMetalCommandEncoder initWithCommandBuffer:] + 56
7  AGXMetalA12                    0xe24ac (Falta UUID a2eac9f81f443d8aa0602263579fe05e)
8  AGXMetalA12                    0x32d5c (Falta UUID a2eac9f81f443d8aa0602263579fe05e)
9  Flutter                        0x287de8 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
10 Flutter                        0x28e4a8 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
11 Flutter                        0x28b584 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
12 Flutter                        0x19cfd0 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
13 Flutter                        0x1920c4 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
14 Flutter                        0x1924b0 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
15 Flutter                        0x58c34 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
16 Flutter                        0x4f63f0 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
17 Flutter                        0x409fc4 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
18 Flutter                        0x341d3c (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
19 Flutter                        0x349bd4 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
20 Flutter                        0x2ee068 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
21 Flutter                        0x2f1098 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
22 CoreFoundation                 0xae268 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
23 CoreFoundation                 0x32c40 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1076
24 CoreFoundation                 0x2d43c __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 328
25 CoreFoundation                 0xbc58 __CFRunLoopRun + 1944
26 CoreFoundation                 0x1f3b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
27 Flutter                        0x2f0f74 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
28 Flutter                        0x2f0788 (Falta UUID e01ae2d7b4293d2bad99555f1db36746)
29 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19a4 _pthread_start + 148
30 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xea0 thread_start + 8
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31029902)